# How to filter sub values from the object using ExpressJS and MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a data from MongoDB where I'm getting all the data of the agent, and I want to get the  `testimonials` with `isDisplayed` is true only. Is there a way in ExpressJS & MongoDB where I can filter the testimonial key?

Here's what I tried

```
const getSingleAgent = expressAsync(async (req, res) => {
  const agent = await Agents.findOne({
    _id: req.params.id,
  });

  res.json(agent);

  } else {
    res.status(404);
    throw new Error("Agent not found.");
  }
});
```

**Actual Result**

```
{
    "_id": "63ea901a85d4fbd62fb887b3",
    "name": "test namee",
    "isDeclined": false,
    "testimonials": [
        {
            "isDisplayed": true,
            "name": "test123123123123123",
        },
        {
            "isDisplayed": false,
            "name": "test123123123123123",
        },
        {
            "isDisplayed": false,
            "name": "test@gmail.com",
        },
    ],
}
```

**Expected Result**

```
{
    "_id": "63ea901a85d4fbd62fb887b3",
    "name": "test namee",
    "isDeclined": false,
    "testimonials": [
        {
            "isDisplayed": true,
            "name": "test123123123123123",
        },
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$elemMatch](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) into a projection stage like this:

```
db.collection.find({
  "_id": "63ea901a85d4fbd62fb887b3",
  "testimonials.isDisplayed": true
},
{
  "name": 1,
  "isDeclined": 1,
  "testimonials": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "isDisplayed": true
    }
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aPcsM46dtQI)

But **be careful**. using `$elemMatch` will only return the first match. Look at [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/38JfXaSmFOA) where there are two `true` but only one is returned.

As explained into docs:

> The `$elemMatch` operator limits the contents of an  field from the query results to contain only the first element matching the $elemMatch condition.

So if you have or want more than one value you can use and aggregation pipelina and [$filter](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) into a `$project` stage:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": "63ea901a85d4fbd62fb887b3",
      "testimonials.isDisplayed": true
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "name": 1,
      "isDeclined": 1,
      "testimonials": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$testimonials",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": [
              "$$this.isDisplayed",
              true
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/p_wzIi-RG80)

Note how in [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OqW4Emo93Qn) if exists two `true` values, both are displayed.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment but there's a little problem about the solution. What happened is I'm getting empty or no data if the agent has no `isDisplayed: true` testimonials. 

Please refer in the link for the reference 
https://mongoplayground.net/p/IcxmqkjBcc_

Comment: Ow it's okay now, I commented the `"testimonials.isDisplayed": true` in the `$match`. Thank you for your help!!!!!!!!

Comment: I've added `"testimonials.isDisplayed": true` to get only documents where exists at least one `isDisplayed` as true, and so the filter is not done in the entire DB. But if it is not a condition you can remove that line.